# Is there a difference between "f" and "F" in Python string formatting?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

To format strings in Python 3.6+, I usually use the lowercase "f" option to include variables. For example:

`response = requests.get(f'{base_url}/{endpoint}?fields={field_list}')`

I've recently seen one of my coworkers who always uses capital "F", instead. Like this:

`response = requests.get(F'{base_url}/{endpoint}?fields={field_list}')`

**Is there a difference between the lowercase "f" and capital "F"? And if yes, when would you use each?**

Comment: AFAIK, there is no difference between "F" and "f".

Comment: Lowercase `f` is easier to type since it doesn't require holding down the Shift key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in the [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), chapter [Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification), both are accepted, and should not differ.

`In source code, f-strings are string literals that are prefixed by the letter 'f' or 'F'. Everywhere this PEP uses 'f', 'F' may also be used.`

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference at all. See the definition of [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in the Python documentation.

> A *formatted string literal* or *f-string* is a string literal that is prefixed with 'f' or 'F'.

No further mention is made of the specific character used to introduce the literal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two. For better understanding, you may go through string formatting.